# How to Round up cart product quantity in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I am working on magento 1.8 version.

I need to set a functionality like if a customer tried to order 10 products the system would either round up to 12 or provide an error message in cart page.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: FYI, Magento has its [own StackExchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

I think this extension will solve your problem. Check this http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-in-multiple-quantities-of-x.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I think giving link is more preferable than explaining about an ready made extension. If I am suggesting about the blog, you are right. But this is about the extension. To explain it theoretically, I have to design all the code which is not possible.

Comment: Well, can you explain how to use the extension, then? Also, if you include the extension name in the answer, the link itself could then be replaced by searching the extension name should the link go dead.